# Upload files with React formData and Fetch

Tags: reactjs, express, file-upload, fetch, multer

**Problem**

In my application, the user can modify his description and profile picture. To do that, I created a controller `updateUser` and a `multer` middleware in the **backend** and a PUT fetch in the **frontend**. However, while I can successfully modify the user's description, when I try to upload a file, I get the following `500 Internal Server Error`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>
            MulterError: Unexpected field<br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\barba\Desktop\Groupomania\backend\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)<br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;at Multipart.&lt;anonymous &gt;(C:\Users\barba\Desktop\Groupomania\backend\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:107:7)<br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;at Multipart.emit (node:events:513:28)<br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;at HeaderParser.cb (C:\Users\barba\Desktop\Groupomania\backend\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:358:14)<br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;at HeaderParser.push (C:\Users\barba\Desktop\Groupomania\backend\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:162:20)<br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;at SBMH.ssCb [as _cb] (C:\Users\barba\Desktop\Groupomania\backend\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:394:37)<br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;at feed (C:\Users\barba\Desktop\Groupomania\backend\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:248:10)<br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;at SBMH.push (C:\Users\barba\Desktop\Groupomania\backend\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:104:16)<br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;at Multipart._write (C:\Users\barba\Desktop\Groupomania\backend\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:567:19)<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried various things, including changing my fetch API with axios, but nothing really works. I also tried to check in other people's React apps how they do (backend and frontend), but I didn't manage to see any crucial difference...

I also did check that my **user put route** had the `multer` middleware.

Finally, I tried to replace the `user_pictureURL` from the **controller**:

`${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/${req.file.filename}` --> `${req.file.filename}`

**Code**
**Backend**

First are my `server.js` and `app.js`:

`server.js`:

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');

function normalizePort(val) {
    const port = parseInt(val, 10);
    if (isNaN(port)) {
        return val;
    }
    if (port >= 0) {
        return port;
    }
    return false;
};

const port = normalizePort('8080');
app.set('port', port);

function errorHandler(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
        throw error;
    }
    const address = server.address();
    const bind = typeof address === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + address : 'port: ' + port;
    switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
            console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges.');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
            console.error(bind + ' is already in use.');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            throw error;
    }
};

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.on('error', errorHandler);
server.on('listening', () => {
    const address = server.address();
    const bind = typeof address === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + address : 'port ' + port;
    console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
});
server.listen(port);
```

`app.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const usersRoutes = require("./routes/user.routes");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
  next();
});

app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));

app.use('/api/users', usersRoutes);
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));

module.exports = app;
```

Next is my **user database model** made with **sequelize**:

```
'use strict';

const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class user extends Model {

    static associate(models) {
    }
  }

  user.init({
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },

    firstName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },

    lastName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },

    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      isEmail: true
    },

    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },

    user_pictureURL: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: null
    },

    user_description: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: "Write your description here!"
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'user',
  });

  return user;
};
```

Then, it is my **user controllers** and more precisely the `updateUser`:

```
const { user } = require("../models");
const fs = require('fs');

let self = {};

self.updateUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const userID = req.params.id;
        const userExist = await user.findOne({ where: { user_id: userID } });

        if (userExist) {
            const userObject = req.file
                ? {
                    ...fs.unlink(`images/${userExist.user_pictureURL}`, () => { }),
                    user_id: userID,
                    firstName: userExist.firstName,
                    lastName: userExist.lastName,
                    email: userExist.email,
                    password: userExist.password,
                    user_pictureURL: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/${req.file.filename}`,
                    user_description: req.body.user_description,
                    createdAt: userExist.createdAt,
                    updatedAt: Date.now()
                }
                : {
                    user_id: userID,
                    firstName: userExist.firstName,
                    lastName: userExist.lastName,
                    email: userExist.email,
                    password: userExist.password,
                    user_pictureURL: userExist.user_pictureURL,
                    user_description: req.body.user_description,
                    createdAt: userExist.createdAt,
                    updatedAt: Date.now()
                };

            const updatedUser = await user.update(userObject, { where: { user_id: userID } });

            if (updatedUser[0] === 1) {
                return res.status(200).json({
                    success: true,
                    message: `User with the id=${userID} has been updated!`,
                    data: updatedUser
                });
            } else {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: `User with the id=${userID} has not been updated!`,
                    data: updatedUser
                });
            }

        } else {
            return res.status(404).json({
                success: false,
                message: `User with the id=${userID} does not exist!`
            });
        }

    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            error: error,
            message: "From userCtlr"
        });
    }
};

module.exports = self;
```

Finally, it's my `multer` middleware:

```
const multer = require("multer");

const MIME_TYPES = {
    "image/jpg": "jpg",
    "image/jpeg": "jpg",
    "image/png": "png"
};

const fileFilter = (req, file, callback) => {
    if (file.mimetype == "image/jpg" || file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype == "image/png") {
        return callback(null, true);
    } else {
        return callback(new Error("The file format is not supported!"), false);
    }
};

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, "images");
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
        const name = file.originalname.split(" ").join("_");
        const extension = MIME_TYPES[file.mimetype];
        callback(null, name + Date.now() + "." + extension);
    }
});

module.exports = multer({ storage, fileFilter }).single("images");
```

**Frontend**
Finally here's the frontend component. As I was not sure that the modals had any impact in the fetch I didn't delete them:

```
function Settings() {
  const userId = sessionStorage.getItem("userId");
  const token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");

  let [userDescription, setUserDescription] = useState("");
  const [pictureFile, setPictureFile] = useState(false);

  let [myModals, setMyModals] = useState({
    updateDescriptionModal: false,
    uploadFileModal: false,
  });

  const getModalHandler = (modalName) => {
    return {
      isOpen: myModals[modalName],
      open: () => setMyModals((state) => ({ ...state, [modalName]: true })),
      close: () => setMyModals((state) => ({ ...state, [modalName]: false })),
    };
  };

  const updateDescriptionModal = getModalHandler("updateDescriptionModal");
  const uploadFileModal = getModalHandler("uploadFileModal");

  const updateAvatar = (event) => {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      setPictureFile(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  const handleUserDescriptionUpdate = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newUserData = new FormData();
    newUserData.append("user_description", userDescription);
    if (pictureFile) {
      newUserData.append("user_pictureURL", pictureFile)
    }
    updateUser(newUserData);
  };

  const updateUser = async (body) => {
    await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/users/${userId}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: body,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.success) {
          if (pictureFile) {
            uploadFileModal.close();
          } else {
            updateDescriptionModal.close();
          }
        } else {
          alert(`${data.message}`);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div id="settingsContainer">

    <button onClick={uploadFileModal.open}>Modify picture</button>
    <button onClick={updateDescriptionModal.open}>Modify description</button>


      <Dialog open={myModals.uploadFileModal}>
        <DialogTitle>Delete account</DialogTitle>

        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            Please upload your <b>new avatar picture</b> here and <b>confirm</b> it!
          </DialogContentText>

          <input
            type="file"
            accept=".png, .jpeg, .jpg"
            onChange={updateAvatar}
          />

        </DialogContent>

        <DialogActions>
          <button onClick={uploadFileModal.close}>Cancel</button>
          <button onClick={handleUserDescriptionUpdate}>Confirm</button>
        </DialogActions>

      </Dialog>

      <Dialog open={myModals.updateDescriptionModal}>
        <DialogTitle>Delete account</DialogTitle>

        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            Please write your <b>new description</b> here and <b>confirm</b> it!
          </DialogContentText>

          <TextField
            fullWidth
            type="text"
            value={userDescription}
            onChange={(event) => setUserDescription(event.target.value)}
          />

        </DialogContent>

        <DialogActions>
          <button onClick={updateDescriptionModal.close}>Cancel</button>
          <button onClick={handleUserDescriptionUpdate}>Confirm</button>
        </DialogActions>

      </Dialog>

    </div>
  );
}
```

I thank in advance anyone who will take the time to try to help me :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the field name used in the frontend matches the field name expected by the backend. In your case, the field name should be "user_pictureURL" as specified in the backend controller code. Check developer consoles network tab to verify what is being sent to the backend. In the frontend code, make sure the form or input element that allows the user to select the file for uploading has the attribute name="user_pictureURL"  Something like this...

```js
<input type="file" name="user_pictureURL" accept=".png, .jpeg, .jpg" onChange={updateAvatar} />
```

In the backend controller code, make sure the multer middleware is set up with the correct field name. Update the multer configuration to use the field name "user_pictureURL". Something like this...

```js
const upload = multer({ storage }).single("user_pictureURL")
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed such an obvious error and even more that I searched for it 7 hours without finding it... Anyways, thank you very much for your help, it really helped me :D!

Comment: Ha ha... I know EXACTLY what you mean! Happens to me all the time. You are welcome :)